# civievent delete download calendar at bottom of registration page

Tags: civievent

I'm trying to use civiEvent for application to a seminar this Fall which will be 10 sessions on irregular dates. I would like to eliminate the Start Date, "When", that civiEvent requires and also the "Download iCalendar..." and "Add event to Google Calendar" widgets at the bottom.

Is there a straightforward way of accomplishing these 3 goals?

Comment: Maybe just a bit of CSS to hide those sections on the registration page?

Comment: You'll also want to have a look at the confirmation email, if you're sending one, because I think that will include the start date too.

Comment: Do you need to use civicrm/event/info at all? You can link people directly to civicrm/event/register and simply put the event info that you do want to include on the top of the registration page.

Comment: But you will still have to hide these on the review and confirmation pages.

Comment: Lars: skipping the /info page and going going directly to /register is a stroke of genius. Produces better flow. I have all the info on a static page on my website and can link to /register. I'll clean up the review and confirmation pages.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Lara SG, You can either skip the Info page and redirect the user to the registration page

Or you can add below css

```
.crm-event-info-form-block .event_date_time-section, .crm-event-info-form-block .iCal_links-section {
   display: none;
}
```

You can add the css via one of the method below

1. Include the css in your theme style.css file
2. Create a new file civicrm.css, add the above code, and place the file in /sites/default/files folder. In Resource url settings(CiviCRM >> Administrator >> System settings >> Resource url) set the Custom CSS URL to [cms.root]/sites/default/files/civicrm.css
3. Add a drupal block, add the css and include the block on /civicrm/event/info page.

Comment: Where/how do i add this css?

Comment: Updated my ans to how to include the css